# SpringBoot Security Logout behaviour

Tags: security, thymeleaf, logout

Hi i use springboot and a custom login form that works.
When i create a form for logout :

```
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out"/>
</form>
```

all works fine.

But if i add a simple link :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{'/logout'}" th:text="#{menu.common.logout}"></a>
</div>
```

The application show a generic error :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 30 14:21:16 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I don't understand the problem. The form and the href point to "/logout" both, but only the first works.

I have this configuration for the security :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                //.logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1800) //1800 sec=30 min
                .key("authKey")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout) note in the spring security docs. If you want to use a get request to log out the users, you'll need to call logoutRequestMatcher after .logout() with the path that you want the users to logout at, in this case "/logout".